How to connect Microsoft one drive to ADF and copy files from one drive in multiple folders and merge few files onedrive to Blob storage?
Require details to create a pipeline to copy data from One drive folders and paste it in azure blob storage. I tried the Logic apps method it works for copying simple files. However wants to know which method is cost effective ADF or Logic Apps.
And the files are in different folders in one drive and need to take union of few files
Tried with logic apps require guidance on ADF part


However wants to know which method is cost effective ADF or Logic Apps

As per the list of connectors in ADF in the documentation

Currently, there is no connector for OneDrive, and it's not supported. That means, you cannot create linked service for it.

As a workaround in this case, you can use logic app or power automate to copy the required files to a temporary location in the Blob. First, create a list of paths of the files that you want from OneDrive and give that list to logic app variable. Then, use a For-each and give each path as item to Get file content by path action of OneDrive.
After getting the file content from the OneDrive, use create Blob action in the same for loop. Extract the file name from the current item path using dynamic expression last(split(items('For_each'),'/')) and give it to the Blob name in the action. Give the extracted file content to the Blob content.

The required files will be copied to the given Blob location.

Now, use ADF to copy the files from this temp Blob location to your target Blob location. To union the files, you can use copy activity Merge files option in the ADF pipeline. Also, you can try dataflow as well as per your requirement.
After designing the pipeline, publish it and you can call the pipeline from logic app so that the pipeline runs every time after the files copy.

